# Javascript listjs multiple filter

Tags: javascript, search, filter, listjs

I am trying to do the multiple search or filter with [ListJS](http://www.listjs.com). Looks like my code doesn't work! Like: fist filter the product & then filter with color & then filter with size.

That works for only normal search.

I am trying to do the multiple search as I have two search field.

```
 <div id="users">   <div class="searchbox">
        <form action="" method="get">
          <input class="search" id="id" placeholder="ID" type="text" />
        </form>   </div>   <div class="searchbox">
        <form action="" method="get">
          <input class="search" id="d2" placeholder="D2" type="text" />
        </form>   </div>

        <script src="javascript/search/list.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

var options = {
<!--  valueNames: [ 'name', 'type', 'keywords-search', 'd2' ]-->
    valueNames: [ 'keywords-search', 'd2' ]
};
var userList = new List('users', options);    
</script>


<script src="javascript/search/list.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var options = {
<!--  valueNames: [ 'name', 'type', 'keywords-search', 'd2' ]-->
    valueNames: [ 'keywords-search', 'd2' ]
};
var userList = new List('users', options);    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#filter-clothes').on('click', function() {
    var idFilter = $('#id').text();
    var itemFilter = $('#d2').text(); 

    console.log('idFilter: ' + idFilter);
    console.log('d2Filter : ' + d2Filter);
    console.log('Applying filter now...');

    featureList.filter(function(item) {
        console.log('Running filter() on item: ('+item+')');
        console.log('item.values().id: ' + item.values().id);
        console.log('item.values().d2: ' + item.values().d2);

        return 
            (idFilter==='All packages' || item.values().id === idFilter) 
            && (d2Filter==='All items' || item.values().d2 === d2Filter);
    });

    return false;
});

</script>
```

Any of you guys have **any simple example**?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the "+" with a comma, like so:

```
valueNames: [ 'keywords-search', 'd2' ]
```

Comment: that works for only normal search.
I am trying to do the multiple search as I have two search field.